# Ho to reference .NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile44

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, portable-class-library

EDIT: Since the problem could not be solved through using the provided answer. I took the the suggestion to switch to .NetStandard which is the reason why the answer was accepted.

I get this error and I can't solve it:

**Your project does not reference ".NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile44" framework. Add a reference to ".NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile44" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.**

**My .csproj looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>10.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{1D5637E9-E724-4943-A535-5B61D0C1C4BC}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>xxx.xxx.xxx/RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>xxx.xxx.xxx</AssemblyName>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile44</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**Since there is already**

```
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile44</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

in it I don't know what to do.

**I restored the NuGets but there was nothing to restore.**

And my project properties look like this:
[image]

I don't know what I can change to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried adding the reference by right-clicking on References under your project and then `Add Reference...`?

Comment: I don't know which one to add there is no dll with this name even in the assembly I downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get [this pack of assemblies](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727) ?
If not, install it and make sure the contents are placed in the correct folder eg `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework`

But, as this is deprecated, the suggestion is to use .NETStandard in stead, see [this article on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/standard/net-standard#comparison-to-portable-class-libraries) for an introduction.

Comment: Okay I downloaded it and now? I restored but nothing happend so do i I unload them or what? ^^ I consider changing the type but first I need to get my project running because the Libraries are already implemented

Comment: Can you try adding a new Portable-Class-Library first?
Normally, your csproj will have an import-tag at the bottom, like:
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />

Comment: The tag exists in the new and the old project

Comment: No only the old one

Comment: Can you provide more code of the old one then?  Or the entire -stripped- project?

Comment: I compared them using VS there ist no difference that could be the problem. I can't provide the projects because of security guidlines of the company. I coworker of mine already implemented the class library as .NetStandard

Comment: I'm really sorry that I can't provide the needed so the question will stay unanswered but I really appreciate your efforts. Thank you!

Comment: If the problem forced you to use .NetStandard, you probably have the best solution you can get!
Cheers!

Comment: Since your answers don't worked but the suggestion of you solved my problem I accepted the answer I hope this is okay for you.

Comment: I can live with that!
Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the issue as well, and any solution above didn't work,
However the problem was that there was an extra project.assets.json and project.nuget.cache file laying in the Obj folder.

This was most likely a leftover from the branch switch.
after deleting this folder / files. The problem was resolved.